How to fix "Input/output error" with chown?
One of my PC (running Debian) broke down recently. I took the HDD and plugged it to an external case with SATA to USB adapter, and tried to access the files from my laptop (Fedora). I can mount the drive and see the files in it. However when I try to open them, it returns the error message:

Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file "...": Input/output error

I had used the drive to store files for my Nextcloud cloud service and edited permissions previously, so I believe it might be some permission issue. I had tried:
sudo chown juzhyo /run/media/juzhyo/d0d39523-6562-4029-be07-b2727b0af006/

Where juzhyo is my laptop user, and d0d39523-6562-4029-be07-b2727b0af006 is the HDD's name. I received:
chown: changing ownership of '/run/media/juzhyo/d0d39523-6562-4029-be07-b2727b0af006/': Input/output error

Is there is any way to recover the files?

"Input/output error" probably means a hardware error. What does dmesg | tail -n 100 show just after the error? If you have space available, copying the device with GNU ddrescue or with a similar program (to work with the copy later) should be your first step. If you don't have space available, finding it is a good zeroth step.

If this is caused by an INTERFACE electronics fault, then getting the data out might be impossible - unless you can replace the drive electronics with something matching the current electronics.
